# How to solve "Array to string conversion" in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

[image]

**I have a Multi-dimensional Array like below**

```
quotation_country_1: ["1", "1", "1"]
quotation_institute_1: ["125", "109", "57"]
quotation_course_1: ["19", "7", "17"]
```

**It has successfully inserted in the database but gives an error for the ajax request "Array to string conversion" So can I get help on how to solve this issue?**

```
public function create_quotation(Request $request)
{
$lead_id = $request->post('selected_lead');

        $data = $request->all();

        if (count($data['quotation_country_1']) > 0) {
            foreach ($data['quotation_country_1'] as $item => $value) {
                $data2 = array(
                    'lead_id' => $lead_id,
                    'interestd_country_id'=>$data['quotation_country_1'][$item],
                    'interestd_institute_id'=>$data['quotation_institute_1'][$item],
                    'interestd_course_id'=>$data['quotation_course_1'][$item],
                );

                DB::table('starter_application_interested_course_ins')
                      ->insert($data2);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You should send data from ajax by json encode not as array, how are you sending it?

Comment: I have sent the data from my laravel form and with ajax

Comment: Are you getting that data in your `create_quotation` method?

Comment: Yes. it's has inserted successfully but after inserted the ajax return in response "Array to string conversion"

Comment: you are not returning anything from this method and the last thing is the query so ... maybe the actual line the error is coming from would be important? don't you think?

Comment: Actually this method is so long and I returning like this 

`return response()->json([
   'status' => 'ok',
   'success' => '<div class="alert alert-success">Quotation has been created.</div>',
  ]);`

Comment: can u check the image I added ?

Comment: You have to use the stacktrace to find what is causing the error, that is the error but what is causing the error, what of your code is causing it ... if you walk down the trace you will get to your code

Comment: I don't know what actually u think? I have facing this problem and I have to solve this problem I try to find out it

Answer (score 0):

just parse array to JSON so you can insert data to field you

Comment: An answer should be a little more detailed.  In most cases it should include some code or the complete code for the solution.  People that ask  have often not the background to understand very short answers - they need to be guided more.

Answer (score 0):

A common use of JSON is to exchange data to/from a web server.

When sending data to a web server, the data has to be a string.

Convert a JavaScript object into a string with JSON.stringify().